# How to show actual size and allocated size on disk of a file in Ubuntu?

Tags: files, disk, disk-usage

I want to know both of them. It's like when you click properties of a file in Windows, it will shows two sizes (actual size and size on disk). How do I do that in Ubuntu?

Comment: How do you define "actual size" and "allocated size"? For example, say you have a file system that supports sparse files, compression, de-duplication, and tail packing, and you have two files with identical content, consisting of highly compressible text and long runs of zeros, sharing their tails with totally unrelated files.

Comment: See also the stat(1) command http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/stat.1.html, it shows blocksize and number of actually allocated blocks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can only answer for command line.

To show the actual size of the file:

`du -b "file"`

To show the allocated size of the file on disk: (= actual size rounded up to whole block size)

`du -B 1 "file"`

Comment: Thank You all :)

Answer (score 4):

If you use PCManFM, you can do this in with a file manager in a GUI format.

[image: file properties]

It's right click menu, under properties - just where Windows puts it, if memory serves.

You should be able to install it with:

```
sudo apt install pcmanfm
```

Other file managers may offer the same functionality, but I know this one does. A quick check indicates that SpaceFM also offers the same.